# Get number of pages in a Folder of every pdf and extract only part of pdf when bigger than 30 sites

Tags: pdf, cmd, vbscript, qpdf

is there a way to filter out all pds in a folder that have more than 30 pages
like qpdf --pages *.pdf
and when a documant have more than 30 pages, then extract only the first and last page and generate a new pdf with the first and last site of bevore created pdfs?
thx

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the exact problem? Are you looking for a tool?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [manual](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/files/qpdf-manual.pdf), `--show-npages` is used to count the pages and should output just the number. Use a `for /f` loop to catch it into a variable. Put another `for` around to process each PDF:

```
@echo off
for %%F in (*.pdf) do (
  for /f %%A in ('qpdf --show-npages "%%f"`) do (
    if %%A gtr 30 (
       qpdf "%%F" --pages 1,r1 -- "%%~dpnF-firstlast.%%~xF"
    )
  )
)
```

(completely untested, because all I know of `qpdf` is the manual, I just found)